# Table field defined as CHAR has values with trailing spaces

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am developing a vba tool to analyse the logs. 
I create a table with CREATE command

```
     CREATE TABLE " & txtImportedLogTbleName & " (日付 DATETIME, WindowsID CHAR, 名前 CHAR)
```

then read the values from a file. 
After importing the data, each field has many spaces (255-the length of the data) after the value. 
Tried Trim to export values to an array and deleted the rs. but no luck so far.

below is the code I Tried.

```
Public Function TrimAllFields(ByVal strSQL As String)
   Dim intX, intArrDimX, intY, intArrDimY, intMyRecCounts As Integer
   Dim arrTemp(), txtRsData As String
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
On Error Resume Next
If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveLast
intMyRecCounts = rs.RecordCount
  If (Err.Number <> 0) Then Call ErrorCatcher(Err.Number, Err.Description, Erl): Err.Clear
  On Error GoTo 0
   If intMyRecCounts > 0 Then
      intArrDimX = rs.RecordCount
      intArrDimY = rs.Fields.Count
      rs.MoveFirst

      ReDim arrTemp(intArrDimX, intArrDimY)
         intX = 0
         While Not rs.EOF And Not rs.BOF
            For intY = 0 To intArrDimY - 1
               If Not rs.Fields(intY).Value = "" Then
                  arrTemp(intX, intY) = Trim(rs.Fields(intY).Value)
                  rs.Edit
                  rs.Fields(intY) = arrTemp(intX, intY)
                  rs.Update
               End If
            Next intY
'            rs.Delete
            rs.MoveNext
             intX = intX + 1
         Wend
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

In Access DDL, a `CHAR` column is fixed-length, 255 characters. Values inserted into that column will be padded with spaces to the full 255 characters.

If you want a variable-length column use `TEXT` instead. The default maximum length is still 255 characters (you can specify a smaller maximum length, e.g., `TEXT(100)`) but the values will not be padded.